# Upper Limit on Matrix Size for Multiplication using cublas gemm function (cublasSgemm)

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc, nsight, cublas

This is the first time ever that I have not been able to get help from answers of previously posted questions.

I have been using **cublasSgemm** quite successfully for **multiplying square matrices.** 
But, recently I observed that if the number of rows or columns increases **beyond 269** (i.e. 270 x 270 matrices and above), I begin to get "Memory Access Violations", when I **debug by enabling Nsight Cuda Memory Checker**. If I do not enable memory checker then there are no exceptions and the results are also correct.

Following is the exact error message

> Memory Checker detected 64 access violations
>
> access violations on store (global memory)

Is it a **limitation of my gpu or the cublasSgemm** function?
What can I do to resolve this issue?

I am using Cuda 6.5 with MS Visual Studio 2012 on Quadro FX 1800M (sm_12). OS is MS Windows 7 64-bit.

I am including a stripped down version of the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
const int m = 269; // for 1 - 269 there are no access violations
// but as soon as m >= 270 Memory Checker throws memory access violations
// Note: the results are correct even with these violations
float *X = new float[m*m];
float *Y = new float[m*m];
float *Z = new float[m*m];
float *devX, *devY, *devZ;
cublasHandle_t handle;
cudaError_t err;
cublasStatus_t err1;

//simple initialization
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < m*m; i++)
{
    X[i] = 1;
    Y[i] = 2;
}

err1 = cublasCreate(&handle);
if(err1 != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

err = cudaMalloc((void **)&devX, m*m*sizeof(*devX));
if(err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

err = cudaMalloc((void **)&devY, m*m*sizeof(*devY));
if(err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

err = cudaMalloc((void **)&devZ, m*m*sizeof(*devZ));
if(err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;


err1 = cublasSetMatrix(m, m, sizeof(*X), X, m, devX, m);
if(err1 != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

err1 = cublasSetMatrix(m, m, sizeof(*Y), Y, m, devY, m);
if(err1 != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
printf("Reached sgemm without error\n");
const float alpha = 1.0f, beta = 0.0f;
// cuda memory checker detects access violations when m > 269
cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, m, &alpha, devX, m, devY, m, &beta, devZ, m);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
printf("reached after sgemm without error\n");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

err1 = cublasGetMatrix(m, m, sizeof(*devZ), devZ, m, Z, m);
if(err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
  return 1;

// just printing a single element for brevity
printf("....%f....", Z[0]); 

cudaFree(devX);
cudaFree(devY);
cudaFree(devZ);
cublasDestroy_v2(handle);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

**EDITED**

[Update: Same result even after disabling TDR, as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA2Ha.jpg)

**EDITED AGAIN**

Compiled and ran the cublas Sample downloaded from:

https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/prac5/simpleCUBLAS.cpp

and again for **N > 500** get the same error as before.

If Cuda Memory Checker is **not enabled** then as before this program runs to completion successfully and displays the "test passed" message.

Actually the access violations begin from N = 350 but at that point they are unpredictable i.e. they occur sometimes and some other times they don't occur. But for N > 500 they always occur

Used cudaDeviceGetLimit(&heap_size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize); to get a heap_size of 3435973836 bytes. So, presumably this isn't the issue either!

**EDITED**
I have now run the sample project code at 'C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v6.5\7_CUDALibraries\simpleCUBLAS'. No luck!!

**EDITED** Could using a single GPU be the reason?

Comment: it must also be noted that there is no problem in allocating the memory for two input matrices and the one output matrix. The GPU has a memory of 1GB.

Comment: There is such a thing as false fault detection. Are you sure these are real? Can you detect them yourself? Does it even matter?

Comment: You might be running into a windows TDR event.  Have you modified the TDR timeout setting at all?

Comment: I've run your code on CUDA 6.5 on a Quadro FX1800 in windows and I don't observe any memory checker issues.  Can you run the simpleCUBLAS [sample code]() correctly (with or without memory checker)?  That is doing a 320x320 sgemm operation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I have tried both disabling TDR and even increased it to as high a value as 60 seconds

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for taking time out to run my code. I will try to run the simpleCublas example and share the results

Comment: Should I take it that there is no limit imposed by cublasSgemm. The limit is only because of hardware constraints.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: To be clear, did you increase 'm' to values greater than 270? Anxiously waiting for your reply, please

Comment: @RobertCrovella Same result even after disabling TDR. Compiled and ran the cublas sample downloaded from https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/prac5/simpleCUBLAS.cpp and again for N > 500 get the same error as before. If Cuda Memory Checker is not enabled then as before this program runs to completion successfully and displays the "test passed" message. Actually the access violations begin from N = 350 but at that point they are unpredictable i.e. they occur sometimes and some other times they don't occur. But for N > 500 they always occur. BTW Heap Size = 3435973836 bytes

Comment: I wasn't really asking if you could find a code somewhere and download and run it.  I was asking *if you could run the simpleCUBLAS CUDA sample code that comes with the CUDA 6.5 install, using the associated project file that is included in that project*.  And I was asking if it ran correctly for you at the default settings, which I believe will result in a 320x320 matrix multiply, since 320x320 is larger than your 270x270 case.  The point is to remove the possibility that any project settings are set incorrectly for your own project(s).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for your continued guidance. I have now run the sample project code at 'C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v6.5\7_CUDALibraries\simpleCUBLAS'. The default value was N = 275, and the code ran fine. Then I began increasing N. At N = 350 and beyond the same memory access violations began occurring intermittently, but after 500 they begin to happen with every run. I am really confused!!!

Comment: to completely remove any chance of tdr kicking in, i have checked tdrlevel in regedit; its set to 0.

Comment: could it be a reason that my laptop has a single gpu and I need to stop other programs from using it while my cuda program is running? Like we do in linux where we quit X window system before using cuda-gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though following is not a 'complete' answer but even then i have decided to share my observation

I have finally decided to switch back to using cuda on linux. 
Using cuda-gdb with memcheck on. Although running linux in level 1 is not fun but all the uncertainity associated with using windows is removed
The above code now runs for even N = 15000.

In short, cublas gemm functions are only limited by hardware capability

Comment: You shouldn't have to switch to runlevel 1.  runlevel 3 should be fine if your objective is to prevent X from running.

Comment: @RobertCrovella but on my ubuntu 14.04 stoping lightdm did not work. So i simply switched to run level 1

Comment: You don't have to stop lightdm.  In runlevel 3 the X service will not be started at boot.  Set runlevel to 3 and reboot.  The advantage of runlevel 3 is that things like networking are still functional, and you can still use linux as a mutliuser environment.